# What is the significance of studying the steady state behaviors of a system? What information do steady state models provide us?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-astronomy

For example, http://www.jameslovelock.org/page31.html In this 1983 paper by Lovelock and Watson modeling Daisyworld, in equations (10) through (14), the paper considers the non zero steady state solutions of the system (when the rate at which white and black daisies are colonizing is zero). From this, the authors deduce that the local temperatures of the white and black daisies stay constant, regardless of initial conditions.

Why are we studying the steady state solutions in the first place? Why was it necessary to consider the steady state solutions to realize the local temperatures of the white and black daisies stay constant over time? Does this mean that if the rate at which the daisies colonized was not zero, then the Daisyworld planet would not experience a planetary temperature stabilization?

Comment: You seem to have tied the general question in the title to some kind of "exobiological" model, one I'm not familiar with.  But generally the study of steady state solutions of dynamical systems is a good starting point for more realistic analysis.  A steady state solution is "in equilibrium", so from a historical perspective one might compare this to static mechanics in engineering (vs. dynamic mechanics).  While static or steady state analysis has some value in itself (e.g. when one wants to maintain equilibrium), it also has value as a preliminary to other studies.

Comment: Could you give me a real world example of when we might want to consider the steady state solutions of a model?

Comment: The steady state happens eventually if we don't interfere. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist:  Actually the property of "decaying to equilibrium" is a rather special property of some systems, one we are familiar with mainly because the systems that don't typically self-destruct.  So it's survival of the fittest, in a sense.

Comment: When we consider steady state behaviors, we allow the rate of one of the components to remain constant as time progresses. So are we assuming all the other components/forces are acting on that component, and as a result, it stays constant?